# Checking if a bit is set using the AND operator

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

In a few code examples, I've seen algorithms to check if a bit is set such as in the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        // count number of elements with i'th bit set
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if ( (arr[j] & (1 << i)) ) // array holds integers
                count++;
```

where the if statement checks to see if the current number in the array has the ith bit turned on. For example, if the number in the current index of the array is 4 (0100 in 4-bit representation) and i is 2 (corresponding to the 3rd bit), the AND operation would be

```
0100
0100 &
= 0100
```

which returns a 4. **Since if statements check for truth values (values of 1 or 0) how would it interpret that AND operation to be true for cases like the one just described?**

Comment: In languages that let you use an integer as a truth value (like C, C++, JS, etc.),  0 is false and non-zero numbers are true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this example compiles, you are very likely doing it in C, C++, or Objective-C (as opposed to Java or C#, where this example wouldn't compile).

Both C and C++ have a rule that interprets zeros as `false` and *all* non-zeros as `true` in contexts where logical expression is expected. Imagine that an implicit `!= 0` is appended to numeric expressions in contexts where a logical expression is expected.

`if` statement requires a logical expression, so any non-zero value is considered `true`. That is why this implementation works.

Answer (score 3):

To build on the other answers, this is actually stated in the C++11 standard.

> 4.12 Boolean conversions [conv.bool]
>
> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
> prvalue of type bool. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false;
> any other value is converted to true. A prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of
> type bool; the resulting value is false.